# AngularJS use ng-click to change $scope "self" value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-click to change the clicked element itself, and use the new value to re-render itself.

**controller:**

```
$scope.Keyboard = {
    click : function(self){
        self.active = false;
    }
};

$scope.keyboards = [
    {'id':1,'chars':[{'char':'a','active':true},{'char':'b','active':true},{'char':'c','active':true}]},
    {'id':2,'chars':[{'char':'d','active':true},{'char':'e','active':true},{'char':'f','active':true}]}
];
```

**html:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="keyboard in keyboards" id="{{keyboard.id}}" class="keyboard">
     <li ng-repeat="char in keyboard.chars" ng-click="Keyboard.click(this)" class="char {{char.active ? '' : 'deactivated'}}">{{char.char}}</li>
</ul>
```

The loops and the initial render are okay. But the "self.active = false" is not forcing a re-render.

I also tried the $apply with no success

Comment: ng-click needs an ng-model to fire.

Comment: try `ng-class="{deactivated: char.active}"`

Answer (score 0):

if that's all you're doing, it would be simpler to just do it like:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wXhzJ8?p=preview

```
<ul ng-repeat="keyboard in keyboards" id="{{keyboard.id}}" class="keyboard">
  <li ng-repeat="char in keyboard.chars"
    ng-click="char.active = false"
    class="char {{char.active ? '' : 'deactivated'}}">
    {{char.char}}
    {{char.active}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

ctrl:

```
$scope.keyboards = [
    {'id':1,'chars':[{'char':'a','active':true},{'char':'b','active':true},{'char':'c','active':true}]},
    {'id':2,'chars':[{'char':'d','active':true},{'char':'e','active':true},{'char':'f','active':true}]}
];
```

Comment: (since you get 2-way binding out of the box anyway)

Comment: This is not all I am doing. I simplified it. I need to process a lot of things and then send it back to re-render. But in some cases, the objects I need to re-render are properties inside loops.